# Dataframes,ordenar valores de columnas de mayor a menor

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ordenamiento

me gustaría ordenador los valores de una columna de un dataframe de mayor a menor y luego restar la diferencia entre el mayor y el menor de todos,como pueod hacerlo?Esto es lo que he intentando y me da **ValueError: This Series is a view of some other array, to sort in-place you must create a copy**

```
df2["UnitPrice"].sort_values( inplace=True, ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Es que `df2['UnitPrice']` es una serie, que corresponde a los valores de la columna `UnitPrice`, lo que tienes que hacer es:

```
df2.sort_values(by=['UnitPrice'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
```

Con esto estarías ordenando el DataFrame completito. A las columnas del DataFrame les puedes aplicar `min()` o `max()` para sacar el mínimo o máximo, directamente, incluso sin necesidad de ordenar:

```
df.UnitPrice.min()
df.UnitPrice.max()
```

---

Si lo que quieres es ordenar solo la serie, por cualquier razón, podrías usar:

```
serie = df['UnitPrice'].copy()
serie.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)
serie.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Y ya operas sobre la serie. `serie[0]` tiene el máximo, `serie[-1:]` tiene el mínimo, y ya les haces lo que quieras. Si tu serie es numérica, puedes usar `np.min(serie)` o `np.max(serie)` con la ventaja que te ahorras los posibles `NaN`.

Y si quisieras tener los métodos encadenados, reasignas la variable y dejas de lado el `inplace`:

```
serie = df['UnitPrice'].copy().sort_values(ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Aunque a mi me parece mucho más legible en tres renglones, como está arriba